# 400 bad request error when setting API: streamingV2_EU

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I get an error when setting api: streamingV2_EU. It works fine with api: derivativeV2_EU. I have a viewer.js file that is quite similar to aps-hub's browser and I get an error in loadmodel().

Similar to this: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-hubs-browser-nodejs/blob/develop/wwwroot/viewer.js

I have tried both with and without the api parameter. The viewer loads fine without api: streamingV2_EU, but then I can't use SVF2.

Answer (score 0):

To load SVF2, not just setting up `api: streamingV2_EU` , the env must be `AutodeskProduction2`, not `AutodeskProduction`.

```js
export function initViewer(container) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction2', api: 'streamingV2_EU', getAccessToken }, function () {
            const config = {
                extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser']
            };
            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, config);
            viewer.start();
            viewer.setTheme('light-theme');
            resolve(viewer);
        });
    });
}
```

ref: `Initializing the Viewer for SVF and SVF2 Support` at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/starting-html/

Comment: I have env: 'AutodeskProduction2' , but still getting the same error.  Is it anything else that I need to change?

Comment: Is this model really hosted in the EU region? If it's not, you cannot use `api: streamingV2_EU`. By default, our samples/tutorials use US region. To make the model and translated results host on our EU server, you must upload the source model file to an EU bucket and request a translation to EU region.

Comment: Yes, the model is hosted in the EU region.
The error says this: {"diagnostic":"Token is not provided in the request."}.
But I don't understand why it only fails with api: 'streamingV2_EU' and not with api: 'derivativeV2_EU'

Comment: Did you pass the access token when calling `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`? A working viewer code example demonstrating this issue would help to understand the problem better.

Comment: Or could you send it to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com` with your model URN?